# Mail.app: Clear Address Auto-Fill Cache

Tags: mac, mail.app, contacts

How do I clear the auto-fill address field cache in Mac Mail?  I have loads of old addresses that I do not send email to.

A removal and reinstallation of the email accounts does not affect the cache.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the menu `Window -> Previous Recipients` - you can select all and delete or be more selective.

Once that's done you may also want to prune your address book or disable mail from auto-filling from there as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if there's only one email address you're worried at the moment just add it to an email then right click on it and select "Remove from Previous Recipient List" and it will no longer come up.